# Create Database FILENAME attribute

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a web application, which does DB export (`export.asp`) and import (`import.asp`).
In the `export.asp` I am trying to create a folder first using VBScript.

```vb
If Not fs.folderexists(Path) Then
    fs.createfolder Path
End If
```

later perform the SQL `CREATE DATABASE` using query

```sql
Use master CREATE DATABASE DB_LOG ON (
    NAME = 'filename_LOG_Data',
    FILENAME = 'c:\PAth\filename_LOG_Data.mdf',
    SIZE = 153
) LOG ON (
    NAME = 'filename_LOG_Log',
    FILENAME = 'c:\Path\filename_LOG_Log.ldf',
    SIZE = 1
) EXEC sp_dboption 'DB_LOG', 'bulkcopy', 'TRUE'
```

With this I am able to create the required .MDF and .LDF files in the mentioned path, however when I try to import the same by selecting filename_LOG_data.mdf from File browse window, I am getting the below error.

> You don't have permission to open this file. Contact the file owner or the administrator to obtain permission.

I am the administrator on the machine. when verified the security settings for both 'Path' folder and .MDF & .LDF files, the security settings (user, groups) are properly set for 'Path' folder, but for the files created with SQL query the security tab in file properties shows "You must have Read Permission to view the properties of this object".

[image: Security properties on .mdf file: "You must have Read Permission to view the properties of this object"]

Question: how to make the SQL `CREATE DATABASE` query create the files with permissions set properly (or) is there any other way to set the security settings.

Comment: SQL Server will restrict database file permissions to the database engine service account and disable inheritance. If your import.asp attaches the database. you shouldn't need direct access to the files since the files are used only by the SQL Server service account.

Comment: @Dan thanks for your reply, i would like to add one more point here, i am not even starting my import operation. The very first that i am doing is, click on the Import option in webpage which will open up the File Dialog to select the .MDF file. Upon selecting the file, and click on OK button in the File dialog, it prompts the error message "You don't have permission to open this file. Contact the file owner or the administrator to obtain permission."

Comment: At the moment, we have an alternate solution, ie., to copy the MDF and LDF files to different location from the actual location and select those files for import operation. immediately after copying the files to new location, the users/adminstrators/SQL account securities are set properly.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting an open error if you are selecting the file name and not opening the file.